# How to break vba code into multiple lines?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a line of code (below) that i would like to break into a new line.  I have tried to insert (_) but haven't had any success.  Any suggestions?

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm "qrysearch", acNormal, "", "([Firm]=[Forms]![search]![cmb_firm] Or IsNull([Forms]![search]![cmb_firm]))And ([City]=[Forms]![search]![cmb_city] Or IsNull([Forms]![search]![cmb_city]))And ([Region]=[Forms]![search]![cmb_region] Or IsNull([Forms]![search]![cmb_region]))And ([Primary Contact First Name]=[Forms]![search]![cmb_firstname] Or IsNull([Forms]![search]![cmb_firstname]))And ([Major Corridor]=[Forms]![search]![cmb_majorcorridor] Or IsNull([Forms]![search]![cmb_majorcorridor]))And ([Minor Corridor]=[Forms]![search]![cmb_minorcorridor] Or IsNull([Forms]![search]![cmb_minorcorridor]))And ([BayAreCommuterBenefitType]=[Forms]![search]![cmb_commuterbenefits] Or IsNull([Forms]![search]![cmb_commuterbenefits]))And ([Bike Parking]=[Forms]![search]![cmb_bikeparking] Or IsNull([Forms]![search]![cmb_bikeparking]))And ([Green Business Program]=[Forms]![search]![cmb_greenbusiness] Or IsNull([Forms]![search]![cmb_greenbusiness]))", , acNormal
```

Comment: Concatenate the string up with a variable - `sMyString = sMyString & " more stuff " `

Comment: Note that the maximum length of a physical line of code can't exceed 1024 characters: that line is 960 characters long! Close call!

Answer (score 3):

Separate the concerns of building the criteria string and invoking it, and then use `_` line continuations and `&` string-concatenation operators to make the massive string literal somewhat readable/maintainable - Rubberduck's [Smart Concat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jP1lURsrcM8) feature can ***really*** help with that: all you'd need to do is hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> wherever you'd like to split the string, and end up with something like this:

```
Const criteria As String = "([Firm]=[Forms]![search]![cmb_firm] Or IsNull([Forms]![search]![cmb_firm])) " & _
    "And ([City]=[Forms]![search]![cmb_city] Or IsNull([Forms]![search]![cmb_city])) " & _ 
    "And ([Region]=[Forms]![search]![cmb_region] Or IsNull([Forms]![search]![cmb_region])) " & _
    "And ([Primary Contact First Name]=[Forms]![search]![cmb_firstname] Or IsNull([Forms]![search]![cmb_firstname])) " & _
    "And ([Major Corridor]=[Forms]![search]![cmb_majorcorridor] Or IsNull([Forms]![search]![cmb_majorcorridor])) " & _
    "And ([Minor Corridor]=[Forms]![search]![cmb_minorcorridor] Or IsNull([Forms]![search]![cmb_minorcorridor])) " & _
    "And ([BayAreCommuterBenefitType]=[Forms]![search]![cmb_commuterbenefits] Or IsNull([Forms]![search]![cmb_commuterbenefits])) " & _
    "And ([Bike Parking]=[Forms]![search]![cmb_bikeparking] Or IsNull([Forms]![search]![cmb_bikeparking])) " & _
    "And ([Green Business Program]=[Forms]![search]![cmb_greenbusiness] Or IsNull([Forms]![search]![cmb_greenbusiness]))"

DoCmd.OpenForm "qrysearch", acNormal, "", criteria, , acNormal
```

That said, consider using *named arguments* instead of `, ,` skipping optional parameters:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "qrysearch", acNormal, "", criteria, WindowMode:=acWindowNormal
```

Note that the `WindowMode` parameter is expecting an [`AcWindowMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.acwindowmode) value, but you're giving it an [`AcFormView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.acformview) value - luckily both have an underlying value of `0` and could be simply omitted because they're both the default value, but still... using the wrong enum can lead to... *interesting* bugs.

So the `OpenForm` call can be simplified to:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "qrysearch", WhereCondition:=criteria
```